# Os links externos não estão 'carregando' ? (ao clicar com o botão esquerdo do mouse)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, slim-lang

Boa noite,

Estou montando uma landingpage para um Retiro que vai acontecer na minha igreja, estou elaborando com (middleman / frameworks [bootstrap]/ HTML slim [ruby]/ heroku), estou criando um link padrão, mais quando clico com botão esquerdo ele não carrega o link mais quando clico com o botão direito e abrir em nova aba, carrega normalmente ?

obs.: "Link interno está funcionando normalmente"

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

link da página -> https://retiroespiritual.herokuapp.com

link para o GitHub do projeto -> https://github.com/rsales/landing_retiro_espiritual

Segue o Código:

```
  /! contatos
  #contato.scroll
  .box2
    .container
      center
        .row
          br
          h2 Contato
          br
          br
          br
          br
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-envelope.fa-4x
            br
              h4 ibiconexaototal@gmail.com
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-phone.fa-4x
            br
              h4 41 9658-7321
          .col-md-3
            i.fa.fa-whatsapp.fa-4x
            br
              h4 41 9658-7321
          .col-md-3
            a href="https://www.facebook.com/conexaototalibi"
              i.fa.fa-facebook-square.fa-4x
              br
                h4 conexaototalibi
        br
        br
        i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-o-up
        a.scroll href="#home" <b>  voltar ao topo</b>
```

Comment: Funcionou normalmente, só o link "Site do Local" não carrega, mas parece ser por causa de um bind do jquery.

Comment: Mais que erro pode ser no jQuery ? será possível problema, pois inseri um js no projeto para scroll suave na própria página, por isso não está carregando os linhais externos, eles eu posso até abrir com o botão direito mais ao clicar diretamente no link não carrega ? @GuilhermeNascimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri, ao usar

```
$(".scroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Todos elementos com `class="scroll"` foram afetados e os elementos filhos também, você aplicou a classe `.scroll` em vários elementos que não são links, por exemplo:

- `#home.scroll` (`<div id="home" class="scroll">`)
- `#oquee.scroll` (`<div id="oquee" class="scroll">`)
- `section#local.scroll` (`<section id="local" class="scroll">`)
- `#convidado.scroll` (`<div id="convidado" class="scroll">`)
- `#contato.scroll` (`<div id="contato" class="scroll">`)

o `event.preventDefault` é executado em todos estes elementos e em seus filhos.

### Solução 1

Ao invés de usar o seletor `$(".scroll")`, use desta maneira `$("a.scroll")`, deve ficar algo como:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.scroll").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
    });
  });
```

### Solução 2

Porém se existe elementos que não são ancoras (`<a>`) então remova a `class="scroll"` dos elementos desnecessários, como os já citados: `#home.scroll`, `#oquee.scroll`, `section#local.scroll`, `#convidado.scroll` e `#contato.scroll`

---

Outro problema (não tem relação direta com o problema informado) é que você adicionou o jQuery duas vezes, eles podem estar conflitando e desencadeando uma série de problemas:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><!--Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed--><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--scroll--><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Pelo que entendi você inclui o jQuery versão `1.11.0` e depois junto com o código do scroll você adicionou a versão `1.4.3`, recomendo remover está versão (pois já é bastante antiga):

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Isto está ocasionando problemas como:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://retiroespiritual.herokuapp.com/'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @GuilhemeNascimento muito obrigado pela ajuda man, consegui corrigir o erro o que estava dando problema era aplicação do (#home.scroll)e as endentasses seguintes não estava carregando links externos.